# Ionic 2 + Firebase fast search

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm trying to inplement filtering in the data that was retrieved from the firebase. As a newbie in Ng2 and Ionic I'm facing a troubles that connected with the speed of a search query. 
I got thouthands of records that keep the word and it's synonym. The goal is to make live searching similar to [Ionic searchbar docs example](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#searchbar) and filter the synonyms.
Since the example shows how to implement filtering on static data I've tried make my code deal with the firebase queries.

[Data model that I have on the Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPgzL.png)

The way I'm retrieving the data is pretty standart, but there are a lot of data that I have to reduce ititial query to 20 items.

I think that pagination is not so necessary, but search query takes minutes! and seems like I can't do anything rather changing data model and nest synonyms inside the as one object related to the word and not thouthands of relations word -> synonym.

The code is pretty standart Angular2 component with AngularFire included

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

public afService:any;
items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, af: AngularFire) {
  this.afService = af;
  this.items = this.initItems(50);
}

// I'm not using provider for now
initItems(qty, serchQuery="guttenavan") {
  return this.afService.database.list('/', {
          query: {
            limitToFirst: qty,
            orderByChild: 'word',  // Search field
            equalTo: serchQuery
          }
        })
}

getItems(ev) {

    this.initItems(50);

    var val = ev.target.value;

    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.items = this.initItems(9999, val.toLowerCase());
      console.log(val.toLowerCase());
    }
  }

}
```

I'll be very glad to hear any suggestions about why it's extremely slow and how I can fix it. 
I'll be also glad to get some valuable information about pagination/infinite scroll with firebase and ionic. 
Thank You.